# Cross-browser file drag-n-drop solution for JS?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for cross-browser desktop file into browser drag example. I've found a few good examples such as [jQuery FileDrop](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) and [jQuery FileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) , awesome examples, but I'm not sure they work in Opera or IE. Could you suggest me a really cross-browser solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a completely cross-browser file drag drop solution, you would need to go in for a file upload control which uses a browser plug-in like Silverlight or Flash. Here is another SO question on the same lines

[Multiple-target cross-browser drag& drop file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491333/multiple-target-cross-browser-drag-drop-file-upload)